# SSH connection refused for non-LAN connection

Tags: server, 18.04, ssh

Here's an odd one, and so far I haven't seen anyone having a similar problem:
I can SSH to my ubuntu server (^18.04) from LAN but once I'm on a different network, with the same PC, I get this very generic message:

`ssh: connect to host [MY_SERVER_NETWORK_IP] port 22: Connection refused`

When reading articles and guides online, they make it seems like it should just work...

Configuration:

- Port 22 is forwarded to my server default static gateway.
- The server is connected to the router with an ethernet cable
- I usually connect to the server with a public/private key

What is missing?

Comment: Hello. Maybe your ISP have restricted the usage of port 22. Try to forward different port to the ssh port of your server and use it. For example you can try with 443, if it is not in use yet.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, there probably is a firewall running on your server, which only allows connections from the Network you can connect from.

You can check any rules allowing or rejecting connections in the server by using the command `sudo iptables --list-rules|grep "A ufw-user-input"`, which lists the active rules.

Otherwise, `sudo ufw status` will show you active rules if Ubuntu's default firewall is running.

Comment: `sudo ufw status` returns "inactive", and the first command yields nothing. Another detail that might be useful: The server is also almost fresh out of the boot drive, all I did was update/upgrade, installed VMs etc.